# ASP.NET Web API : JsonIgnore attribute only for set or get

Tags: asp.net, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, annotations

Using Entity Framework table class.

I need to exclude a few properties and hence I am using `[JsonIgnore]` which is perfectly fine when I want to exclude both for set and get.

```
public class NamTable
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string mail { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public System.DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

But I need to exclude few properties only for set or get.

Examples are `id` and `timestamp` which are not needed during insert or set, but I need them when I do a get request. So which annotation do I need to add to achieve this?

I know below is wrong but looking similar method...

```
public class NamTable
{
    public long id { get; [JsonIgnore] set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string mail { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime timestamp { get; [JsonIgnore] set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need such a thing?

Comment: Actually, you just need a Messaging Pattern in which the input and outputs are different. While you are are trying to insert you have to use **SomeClassInputDto** , and in case of using the response you have to use **SomeClassOutputDto**.